# How to pass values containing line breaks through Ajax in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I am trying to update a textarea with an `address` through Ajax:

**application.js**

```
$("#invoice_project_id").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/invoices/get_recipient',
        data: 'project_id=' + this.value,
        dataType: 'script'
    })
});
```

**invoices_controller.rb**

```
def get_recipient
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @recipient = project.person.address
end
```

**get_recipient.js.erb**

```
$('#invoice_recipient').val("<%= @recipient %>");
```

Apparently, a textarea cannot be populated through Ajax this way, probably due to the line breaks in the `address`.

When I use another attribute, e.g. `first_name`, the whole thing works pretty well:

```
@recipient = project.person.first_name
```

How can I get this to work with an `address` as well?

I guess the line breaks inside the addresses need to be escaped somehow, but I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you send text instead of script and make the `val()` update in ajax success instead. WOn't need to escape line breaks if it is text. If send text would use  `$.get( url, function(response){  $('#invoice_recipient').val(response);})`

Comment: Thanks but where exactly would I place that line? Could you do me a favour and insert it into my code above?

Comment: would replace all the `$.ajax`. `$.get` is a shortcut method of `$.ajax` with some of the options already set to make for code simplification

Answer (score 1):

If you can replace change the jQuery being returned with the text in it, and send straight text you can do:

```
$("#invoice_project_id").change(function() {
   var value=$(this).val();
    $.get('/invoices/get_recipient', {project_id= : value}  function(response) {
        $('#invoice_recipient').val(response);
    })
});​
```

Sending the line breaks as straight text as opposed to script should preserve them when they get added to textarea

Comment: OK thanks, but I am getting this error now: `Couldn't find Project without an ID`. Are you sure I don't need to pass some more options, e.g. the `project_id`?

Comment: OK, I had to make some slight adjustments to your code above to get it working. But the output is now exactly as with my initial code sample. It still doesn't work with multiline fields. What am I missing here?

Comment: in a browser console you can inspect the full ajax request including response which will read like text and would see separate lines if what you are sending contains the line breaks. Perhaps server code is stripping them

Comment: another thought... is ouput being sent with a script header as in original? Check headers in browser conaole also

Comment: Everything works perfectly when an address does *not* contain any line breaks. Once it *does* contain a line break, it prevents javascript from executing it. I don't get any error in my console but the code just stops.

Comment: I think **[this blog post](http://databasically.com/2009/03/18/updating-textarea-with-ajax-unterminated-string-literal/)** could be part of the solution but I wasn't able to get the code working that is suggested there.

Comment: OK, I managed to get it working using [this blog post](http://databasically.com/2009/03/18/updating-textarea-with-ajax-unterminated-string-literal/). Thanks for helping me out here.